# Junit using Mock Objects

Tags: junit4, easymock

```
MyClass{

public void myfunction(){
AnotherClass c=new AnotherClass();
c.somethod();//This method sets some values of the AnotherClass object c;

}
}
```

I have the above scenario to be tested.How do I check if the value of *AnotherClass* Object *c* is set properly.I understand that I have to use Mock Objects for these.But couldn't figure out how because here I cannot pass the mock object of AnotherClass to myfunction because of the above design.Can anybody help me?

Comment: try to test the outcome of calling myfunction() method. if variable 'c' is a method local variable what happens when you call c.somethod() ? what is the outcome that is externally observable ?

Comment: The outcome cannot be externally available. c.somemethod() is setting the vaules of c which was created in the myfunction()

Comment: you should unit test functionality that is made available to outside in some form. if doing c.somethod() doesn't do anything that is externally visible then IMHO you don't need to unit test it

Comment: I agree with @DevBlanked, you should only try to test what is externally visible. I'm guessing your example is sample code and, as such, is missing some of the implementation details that would possibly make it testable. For example, if `c` is passed to some other mockable object, then captures could be used and the values of `c` could be asserted. Failing that, if you really want to find out if `somethod` was called or if `c` was altered, then a redesign is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you really want to do this should do a redesign like follows (as Dan has also suggested)

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class TestingMock {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyClass target = Mockito.spy(new MyClass());
        AnotherClass anotherClassValue = Mockito.spy(new AnotherClass());
        Mockito.when(target.createInstance()).thenReturn(anotherClassValue);
        target.myfunction();
        Mockito.verify(anotherClassValue).somethod();
    }

    public static class MyClass {

        public void myfunction(){
            AnotherClass c = createInstance();
            c.somethod();//This method sets some values of the AnotherClass object c;
        }

        protected AnotherClass createInstance() {
            return new AnotherClass();
        }
    }

    public static class AnotherClass {

        public void somethod() {

        }

    }
}
```

You will see that commenting out c.somethod() makes the test fail.
I'm using Mockito.